# Register Powershell SnapIn to specific version of Powershell

Tags: powershell, pssnapin

I am trying to run an **Exchange Management Shell** script via managed code. 
Our PowerShell version is version 4.
I am trying to use the `runspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapin()` method to add the exchange SnapIn `Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010`, however this line fails, giving :

> *no snapins have been registered for Powershell version 4.*

A quick `Get-PSSnapIn -registered` shows the **SnapIn** is installed but registered to PS version 1.

In **regEdit**, I have found the registry key for the snapIn for PowerShell v1, used the export function to script the key, changed the target version to 4 and ran the export command, which has created the new key '4' under PowerShell as expected, with the snapin details copied across. However I still get the '*no snapins have been registered for Powershell version 4.*', even though the key is there in the registry.

Is there something else I should be doing to register the snapin to PowerShell version 4?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's probably a module, not a snapin.  If you use InitialSessionState instead of RunspaceConfiguration, you can use iss.ImportModule, but I think that api isn't available on RunspaceConfiguration, so you need an explicit Import-Module command to run once the runspace is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that this is a 32/64 bit build issue. After I set the target build to x64 in VS and redeployed, all magically seemed to work fine.
The error message regarding Powershell versions is a massive Red Herring in this case.